# what are options availble for rich reports implementation in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to implement rich reporting features in one of our asp.net mvc based web applications. The required features in the reports are

1. Graphs
2. Charts
3. Grouping, sub totals, page breaking, etc
4. Ability to export to excel, pdf, csv and other formats
5. Printing Support

We are ready to purchase commercial controls(if free ones are not available). Please suggest us the best of available options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what rich reporting packages are out there that are 100% ASP.NET MVC-driven.  I've seen a few talk about MVC.

But technically, you don't need an MVC-version of reporting controls.  ASP.NET MVC allows you to use standard ASP.NET functions, such as WebForms, postbacks, server controls, etc.  This is easy as a drop-in-place solution because ASP.NET MVC's default Convention-over-Configuration programming checks to see if a directory or file exists first, before being routed through the controller logic.

So, if there are no Asp.Net Mvc versions of graphs and charts you like - then fear not, you can fall back to the ones you've used for your previous asp.net forms projects.  Even though I recommend sticking it into a dedicated directory (i.e. /reports) to keep a clean website.

Comment: Alright. So all i need to identify is a set of controls that works with asp.net(no need to look something very specific to asp.net). 

I've not used any reporting controls so far. Please suggest me if you know any.

Comment: Telerik has some decent controls, even though they can be bloated if you don't use MS Ajax.  ComponentArt is another widely used vendor, even though they can be bloated as well.  Xceed is another one.  If you are wanting something free, ASP.NET 3.5's website has released a few decent ones: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try and use a regular web form for the reports, with graphic, charts, and any other ontrol you might need. MVC views and web forms **can** live in the same project, noting wrong with that. At least until you find a way to do it using a MVC view.

In my own opinion, you don't have to do everything MVC in a project, you are "allowed" to do whatever you need to do to make your application work the way you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the asp.net [chart control](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/11/24/new-asp-net-charting-control-lt-asp-chart-runat-quot-server-quot-gt.aspx) which is free to download and supported with ASP.net MVC

Answer (score -1):

I found this while searching for something similar.

http://www.componentsource.com/products/syncfusion-essential-studio-aspnet-mvc/index-gbp.html

I haven't used it though.  There is a trial download.